# Can someone provide me with an IndexableText.Text example in javascript?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm working with the google drive api and am trying to set some metadata that the user enters. I was wondering if anyone could provide an example of how to use the indexableText or if there was a better way to insert metadata at this point!

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

From the [Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/file#saving_indexable_text) itself. You can find here that, Drive automatically indexes documents for search when it recognizes the file type. This includes text documents, PDFs, images with text, and other common types. If your app saves other types of files (drawings, video, shortcuts), you can improve the discoverability by supplying indexable text.

Indexable text is indexed as HTML. If you save the indexable text string `<section attribute="value1">Here's some text</section>`, then "Here's some text" is indexed, but "value1" is not. Because of this, saving XML as indexable text isn't as useful as saving HTML.

Also keep in mind that:

- The size limit for `contentHints.indexableText` is 128K.
- Don't try to sort text in order of importance; the indexer does that very efficiently for you.
- Indexable text should be updated by your application with each save.
- Make sure the text is related to the content of the file.

Also check this [tutorial](http://www.advancedwebranking.com/blog/make-javascript-indexable-by-google/) on How to make JavaScript Indexable.

It is explained here, that you need to use `<noscript>` tag to make JavaScript based content indexable.